# Adding Multiple web pages to UIWebview in a Page-Based app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am working on making a paged app that will load a separate HTML page on each page. I am using the already given example that Apple has provided and rigged it to make the label dissapear and a few other things. Most tutorials I have seen do not cover this idea at all.

I need to be able to make an array of webpages and using one UIWebview display those pages, obviously one HTML file per page. What will be the most efficient way to do this that is up to date with iOS5 or is there a recent tutorial I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: Which Apple sample code are you using?

Comment: So which app would that be? What is it called?

Comment: just start a project, and use the page based app one. Its on the 4.2 version of xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you have you could serialize the HTML data in a single file (such as a plist) or have them as separate files in a directory.

Based on the template you are using, you would

- change the view in `DataViewController` to a `UIWebView`;
- then override the `viewControllerAtIndex` method in your `ModelController` and pass the path to your HTML page as the data object;
- and finally load the HTML in the `viewWillAppear` method of your `DataViewController`.

Voilà, here is your tutorial!

Comment: I would first have to write it ... ;-<. What part do you have problems with?

Comment: i am loading the epub file in to the webview  1]extract the epub 2]load the contents in to webview 3] the contents may have more than 10 html files so when i load the content each by each in webview its making lot time to load because the text are in arabic